# Update slider range from renderUI in R

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, slider

I"m attempting to update my distributions and plot from a slider range.  The catch is the first time the histogram is displayed it creates a range from an input file, then I would like the user to have the ability to change the range. I've figured out how to display the range in the slider by using renderUI on the server side, but can't figure out how to implement the update with new ranges.

UI:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("NewData", "Upload File")
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                   tabPanel("Distributions 1",plotOutput("hist1.plot"))
                   ),
       tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                    tabPanel("Distributions 2",plotOutput("hist2.plot"),
                    uiOutput("update.mod.hist.range"))
       )
                
) # close mainPanel
) # close sidebarLayout
) # close fluidPage
) # close shinyUI
```

Server:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input,output){ # open shiny server
  
  ev = reactiveValues()
  
  
  observeEvent(input$NewData,{
    if(is.null(input$NewData))
      return(NULL)
    
    ev$sim.data = read_excel(input$NewData$datapath)

  })
  
  output$hist1.plot = renderPlot({
    
    req(ev$sim.data)
    
    amount = c(sapply(ev$sim.data$amt,function(x){runif(1000,1,x)}))
    
    cat = (rep(ev$sim.data$cat, each = 1000))
    
    hist.data = data.frame(amount,cat)
    names(hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    
    ev$hist.data = hist.data
  
    hist.data$cat = factor(hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
    pricedata = ddply(hist.data, c("cat"), summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                      plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
    pricedata = pricedata[order(pricedata$avg),]


    ggplot(hist.data, aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
      geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
      theme_test()+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+


      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+


      geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+


      facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
      scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))

  }) #close renderPlot
  

     output$hist2.plot = renderPlot({ # open renderPlot
    
     low = mean(ev$hist.data$amount)-sd(ev$hist.data$amount)
     high = mean(ev$hist.data$amount)
     
     ev$low = low
     ev$high = high
 
      mod.amount = runif(1000,low,high)
      cat = rep("x",1000)
    
      mod.hist.data = data.frame(mod.amount,cat)
      names(mod.hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    
       #mod.hist.data$cat = factor(mod.hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
       pricedata = ddply(mod.hist.data, c("cat"), summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                         plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
       pricedata = pricedata[order(pricedata$avg),]
    
    
       ggplot(mod.hist.data, aes(x=amount))+
         geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
         theme_test()+
         geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+
    
    
         geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
    
    
         geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
    
    
         #facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
         scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
         scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
    
     }) #close renderPlot

   output$update.mod.hist.range = renderUI({
    
       sliderInput("update.mod.hist.range","Update this Histogram",
                   min = min(ev$hist.data$amount),
                   max = max(ev$hist.data$amount),
                   value = c(ev$low,ev$high)
                   )
     })
}) # close shinyServer
```

I don't think there is the ability to attach files. The input file in excel is very simple:

amt  cat
50    a
60    b
70    c

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("NewData", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx") 

    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                   tabPanel("Distributions 1",plotOutput("hist1.plot")
                            ,uiOutput("updaterange")
                            )
                   
      ),
      tabsetPanel( type = "tabs", #Open panel
                   tabPanel("Distributions 2",plotOutput("hist2.plot")
                            #,uiOutput("update_mod_hist_range")
                            )
      )
      
    ) # close mainPanel
  ) # close sidebarLayout
) # close fluidPage


server <- function(input,output){ 
  
  ev = reactiveValues()
  
  
  observeEvent(input$NewData,{
    if(is.null(input$NewData))
      return(NULL)
    
    ev$sim.data <- read_excel(input$NewData$datapath)
    req(ev$sim.data)
    
    amount = c(sapply(ev$sim.data$amt,function(x){runif(1000,1,x)}))
    
    cat = (rep(ev$sim.data$cat, each = 1000))
    
    hist.data = data.frame(amount,cat)
    names(hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    hist.data$cat = factor(hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
    
    low = mean(hist.data$amount)-sd(hist.data$amount)
    high = mean(hist.data$amount) + sd(hist.data$amount)
    
    ev$low = low
    ev$high = high
    ev$hist.data <- hist.data
    
    output$updaterange = renderUI({

      sliderInput("update_mod_hist_range","Update this Histogram",
                  min = min(ev$hist.data$amount),
                  max = max(ev$hist.data$amount),
                  value = c(ev$low,ev$high)
      )
    })
    
    
    pricedata = ddply(hist.data, c("cat"), plyr::summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                      plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
    pricedata = pricedata[order(pricedata$avg),]
    
    output$hist1.plot = renderPlot({
      
      ggplot(subset(hist.data, cat!="" ), 
             aes(x=amount, fill = cat))+
        geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
        theme_test()+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = 1)+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
        scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
      
    }) #close renderPlot
    
  })

  observeEvent(input$update_mod_hist_range,{
    if(is.null(input$update_mod_hist_range)) return(NULL)
    
    mod.amount = runif(1000,input$update_mod_hist_range[1],input$update_mod_hist_range[2])
    
    #mod.amount = runif(1000,ev$low,ev$high)
    
    
    cat = rep("x",1000)
    mod.hist.data = data.frame(mod.amount,cat)
    names(mod.hist.data) = c("amount","cat")
    
    #mod.hist.data$cat = factor(mod.hist.data$cat, levels = c("a","b","c"))
    pricedata2 = ddply(mod.hist.data, c("cat"), plyr::summarize, avg = mean(amount), minus.stdev = mean(amount)-sd(amount),
                       plus.stdev = mean(amount) + sd(amount))
    pricedata2 = pricedata2[order(pricedata2$avg),]
    output$hist2.plot = renderPlot({ # open renderPlot
      
      ggplot(mod.hist.data, aes(x=amount))+
        geom_histogram(color="white", alpha = .8, position = 'identity', binwidth = 5)+
        theme_test()+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = avg), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = 1)+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = minus.stdev), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept = plus.stdev), data = pricedata2, color = "black", size = .75, linetype = "dotted")+
        
        #facet_grid(cat ~., scales = "free")+
        scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),name = "Count")+
        scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name="\nAmount", limits = c(0,100))
      
    }) #close renderPlot
  
  
})
 
     
} # close shinyServer

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You will get this output, where changes to the slider changes the plot below the slider.

[image: output]

It was not clear if you wanted the first plot also should be dependent on the slider. You can easily update the program, if necessary.

Comment: ahhh, two different events and then an if statement.  I get it now.   Thanks!